# Upgrading a web site project from .NET 2.0 to 4.5.2: missing ScriptManager, ScriptService, ScriptMethod

Tags: asp.net-ajax, .net-4.5

Tried to upgrade a .NET 2.0 web site project in VB to 4.5.2 and that broke compilation with the errors

```
BC30002 Type 'ScriptManager' is not defined.
BC30002 Type 'System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod' is not defined.
BC30002 Type 'System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService' is not defined.
```

Tried `Import System.Web.UI` but it did not work and there was a warning that the import was unnecessary. Same with `System.Web.Extensions`.

The first error occurs on the line:

```
Public ReadOnly Property ScriptManagerObject() As ScriptManager
    Get
        Return Me.ScriptManager1
    End Get
End Property
```

The member is defined in ASPX as

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="AutoComplete.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

What should I do to point the compiler at the correct namespace for `ScriptManager` etc?

**EDIT:**

Tried adding this line to the ASPX page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web"%>
```

Did not work.

Tried adding a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` for 4.0 framework. Did not work.

Tried deleting the `ScriptManager1` object from ASPX and re-adding it from the Toolbox under the same name. It is still not found as a member of the page's class. How can we solve this mystery?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19128973/2721750
Reverting to 3.5 and repeating the upgrade to 4.5.2 
Apparently it makes more changes to `web.config` and includes tons more assembly references, some of whom might have been missed on the initial upgrade.